# How to call an action (NuxtJs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to call an action in my vue from my store.

This is my file aliments.js in my store:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.use(Vuex, axios);

export const state = () => ({
  aliments: {},
})
export const mutations = () => ({
  SET_ALIMENTS(state, aliments) {
    state.aliments = aliments
  }
})
export const actions = () => ({
  async getListAliments(commit) {
    await Vue.axios.get(`http://localhost:3080/aliments`).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      commit('SET_ALIMENTS', response);
    }).catch(error => {
      throw new Error(`${error}`);
    })
    // const data = await this.$axios.get(`http://localhost:3080/aliments`)
    // commit('setUser', user)
    // state.user = data;
    // return state.user;
  }

})
export const getters = () => ({
  aliments (state) {
    return state.aliments
  }
})
```

I want to diplay a list of aliments in my vue with :

`{{ this.$store.state.aliments }}`

I call my action like this :

```
<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['loggedInUser', 'aliments']),
    ...mapActions(['getListAliments']),
    getListAliments() {
      return this.$state.aliments
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I don't understand where is my mistake :/

NB: I also tried with a onclick method on a button with a dispatch('aliments/getListAliments')... but doesn't work...

Comment: what is `this.$state`? Didn't you mean `this.$store`? (in the computed property `getListAliments`)

Comment: this.$state.aliments is to retrieve the state aliments from my store. I make a mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're mapping your actions in the "computed" section of the component, you should map it in the "methods" section !

Comment: I just tried and i got the same error: "vuex.esm.js?2f62:420 [vuex] unknown action type: aliments/getListAliments"

Answer (score 0):

Hi and Welcome to StackOverflow

to quickly answer to your question, you would call an action as:

```js
this.$store.dispatch('<NAME_OF_ACTION>', payload)
```

or though a `mapActions` as

```js
...mapActions(['getListAliments']), // and you call `this.getListAliments(payload)`
```

or yet

```js
...mapActions({
  the_name_you_prefer: 'getListAliments' // and you call `this.the_name_you_prefer(payload)`
}),
```

for getters, it's the same process, as you already have 2 definitions `['loggedInUser', 'aliments']` you simply call the getter like if it was a computed value `<pre>{{ aliments }}</pre>`

or when we need to do a bit more (like filtering)

```
getListAliments() {
    return this.$store.getters['aliments']
}
```

---

**But** I can see your store is as we call, one-to-rule-them-all, and because you are using Nuxt, you can actually leverage the [**module store**](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#modules-mode) very easy

as your application grows, you will start store everything in just one store file (the `~/store/index.js` file), but you can easily have different stores and instead of what you wrote in `index.js` it can be easier if you had a file called, taken your example

`~/store/food.js` with

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const state = () => ({
    aliments: {},
})

export const getters = {
    aliments (state) {
        return state.aliments
    }
}

export const mutations = {
    SET_ALIMENTS(state, aliments) {
        state.aliments = aliments
    }
}

export const actions = {
    async getListAliments(commit) {
        await axios.get('http://localhost:3080/aliments')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                commit('SET_ALIMENTS', response.data);
            }).catch(error => {
                throw new Error(`${error}`);
            })
  }
}
```

BTW, remember that, if you're using [Nuxt `serverMiddleware`](https://blog.lichter.io/posts/nuxt-with-an-api/), this line

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3080/aliments')...
```

would simply be

```
axios.get('/aliments')...
```

and to call this store, all you need is to prefix with the filename, like:

```
...mapActions(['food/getListAliments'])
// or
...mapActions({ getListAliments: 'food/getListAliments' })
// or
this.$store.commit('food/getListAliments', payload)
```

another naming that could help you along the way:

- on your action `getListAliments` you're actually fetching data from the server, I would change the name to `fetchAliments`
- on your getter `aliments` you're actually returning the list, I would name it `getAllAliments`

have fun, Nuxt is amazing and you have a great community on [Discord](https://discord.nuxtjs.org/) as well for the small things :o)

---

**EDIT**

also **remember** that `actions` are set in `methods`

so you can do:

```
...
export default {
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['getListAliments]),
    },
    created() {
        this.getListAliments()
    }
}
```

and in your Store action, please make sure you write

```
async getListAliments({ commit }) { ... }
```

with **curly braces** as that's a deconstruction of the property passed

```
async getListAliments(context) { 
   ...
   context.commit(...)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your tips ;)  I'm using the module mode for my store. Is not "dispatch" to call an action?

Comment: `store.commit()` -> mutations | `store.dispatch()` -> actions ~:o)

Comment: Yes but you said "you would call an action as: this.$store.commit('<NAME_OF_ACTION>')".  I tried your methods but nothing changes, got nothing. It says that it doesn't know my action getListAliments

Comment: true, my bad... I'll change... what I wrote in the comment is correct :)

Comment: @MelvynROUAULT I've edited the answer, at the bottom I've found the source of your problem, but everything I wrote is correct and you should take on the naming convention as well...

Comment: I'm trying to follow your advices but in my store i have to write it like that :  async getListAliments({ commit }) { ... } or like the second option : async getListAliments(context) { 
   ...
   context.commit(...)
}

Comment: @you choose the best method for you, I personally use `fetchAliments(context)` as it makes persons that read the code less prone to made mistakes, and `fetch` is a better word for what you are doing, as `getAllAliments` should be a getter, maybe later you would have `getAlimentByName` :)

Comment: I did this in my component :
```methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      getListAliments: 'aliments/getListAliments'
    }),
    fetchAliments() {
      this.$store.dispatch(this.getListAliments)
    }
```
But ```{{ this.$store.state.aliments }}``` still empty. So I think my problem is my commit but I don't understand what's wrong

Comment: @MelvynROUAULT you need to do `fetchAliments() { this.$store.dispatch('aliments/getListAliments') }` and no need to map ... go to [Nuxt discord](https://discord.gg/bjkmbk), find me (balexandre) and let's talk there